# Latest xcb-proto and libxcb version on RHEL 7.0

Tags: linux, rhel, xcb

what is the latest version of xcb-proto and libxcb on RHEL 7.0?

Till now we have explored that xcb-proto's latest version is 1.8 and libxcb's is 1.9. But we are still getting the following error in a multi-threaded program:

java: xcb_conn.c:186: write_vec: Assertion `!c->out.queue_len' failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my centos 7, the command

```
yum info libxcb
```

returns a version of 1.9 of xcb

and the command

```
pkg-config --variable=xcbproto_version xcb
```

returns a versions of 1.8 for xcbproto

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.04 32bit:

- apt-get install libxcb1-dev
- apt-get install libxcb1-udeb
- apt-get install libxcb1

was helpful for me.